# Typescript extend DataType alternately fails to compile

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In my `extensions/date.ts` file, I have the following extension:

```
interface Date {
  addDays: (days: number) => Date
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days: number): Date {
  if (!days) return this;
  let date = this;
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
};
```

In `server.ts`, it is imported first in line:

```
import './extensions/date';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config()
...rest imports
```

And it actually compiles, and proved to be working! but sometimes when I make changes and the app is recompiled automatically using `nodemon` and runs using `node-ts`, the app breaks and TS no longer recognises `Date.addDays()` as a valid function.

To solve it temporarily I used to relocate the import to a higher place in the chain, but now I have nowhere else to climb.

The error is the good old 2339:

> Property 'addDays' does not exist on type 'Date'. (2339)

Has anyone tackled this? Perhaps a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite `global` with you `Date` interface in (e.g.) `date.ts` file

```js
export {}

declare global {
  interface Date {
    addDays(days: number):  Date
  }
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days: number): Date {
  if (!days) return this;
  let date = this;
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
};
```

`export {}` is hack to avoid `File date.ts is not a module.` error

Then in main file you can `import './date'` and call `let fn = (arg: Date) => arg.addDays(1);` without error

```js
import * as x from './date';

let fn = (arg: Date) => arg.addDays(1);
```